# Specify multiple day event duration in calcurse

Tags: command-line, calendar

I have recently started using the shell application calcurse to handle my appointments. In order to specify a multiple day event duration without converting days to hours, I would like to use the suggested syntax `+xxxdxxhxxm` when creating a new event.

Unfortunately, I was not yet able to get this to work and instead, when trying to match this pattern, receive an `Invalid end time/duration` error. For example, neither `+xxx1xx1xx1`, `+x1x10x10`, nor `+1:10:10` (which obviously does not match the pattern, however, would be consistent with the `+hh:mm` duration syntax) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace 'x' with the amount of days/hours/minutes you want.
For example use `+10d5h30m` for 10 days 5 hours and 30 minutes.